# Keep the modal on top of the index page in case of validation error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an index view and a modal pop up that are invoked by a button, I added some validations to the modal. When I enter to the action (in the controller) and everything is OK I redirect to the index view, which is OK, but the problem is when the validation failed and the model state is not valid I want it to stay in the modal with the errors. Currently when I call to the partial view (like following) it opens a new page with the the validation errors and not on top of the index like before it calls to the controller. How should I solve it? I.e. in case of validation error, keep the modal on top the index page.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(
    [Bind(Include = "Id,username,address")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.GCollection.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return PartialView("myModal", user);
}
```

This is in the view:

```
<div id="modal" >
    @Html.Partial("MyModal", this.Model.Model)
</div>
```

Comment: As far as i m understanding ur problem....for ur modal pop validations u can use jquery for complete validations so that when data will be posted ur modalstate will be valid...if it is not helpful to u ... plz post some more code so that i can properly understand ur problem...

Comment: Can you put some example for the jquery validaton in the modal?

Comment: No sir jquery validations do not work in modal u have to use jquery validation in ur view only...

Comment: But the problem is that the modal is alwayes closed...

Comment: in your view use Ajax form instead html form so that page not refreshes and state remians unchanged